# General workflow for git-svn bridge for 2 teams

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, dcommit

Lately I read many things about GIT-SVN bridge, tried it myself but somehow I fail when things get rough.

**The environment**
We are 2 teams: once uses SVN, the other is rebel and uses GIT. In order to sync, I created a bridge between the 2 repos. 
The SVN team has x developers pushing 10 times a day and having mostly a red build, GIT team has 6 developers and they want to fetch only once a week or when they have something to commit so they keep the build mostly green.

**Use case:**
The "bridge" is not automated (yet), therefore it is on my computer so I am responsible to merge branches and dcommit them correctly.
So, the GIT team is splitted in 2: some of them working on branch "branch1" and the rest working on "branch2". They always work in pairs so when "branch1" is done, we create another branch for next task.

**What I tried to do:**
In order to keep it clear, I created a branch from master called "masterSpace". I do git-svn rebase on master every morning, then I merge the changes into masterSpace. A developer creates from masterSpace "branch1" when needed where devs commit stuff. When they are done, I have to commit everything on SVN. I tried like this

```
merge "branch1" into "masterSpace".
checkout master
git svn rebase
git rebase masterSpace
git dcommit
git checkout masterSpace
merge "master" into "masterSpace".
```

Then a developer would create a new branch from this masterSpace having everything up-ti-date and the process repeats itself

**Problem:**
I tried this with branches that had a single commit and worked great, but things got rough after like 2 weeks of work ... then my workflow failed.
After I decommited , the same commits had different IDs on master and on "masterSpace" so next time I was trying to dcommit I got hell of a lot of conflicts. Even after I merged master into masterSpace.
I even tried a simple scenario where:

```
 I have a "branchX" with changes
 I merge them on "masterSpace"
 rebase them on master and finally dcommit them.
 Then I made a single change on "masterSpace" 
 I rebased it into "master"
```

After this, I was like 10 commits ahead (because of the IDs of the previous commits I guess). So...dead end

**Q1: Solution?**
What would be the correct workflow for our environment and usecases so that both GIT and SVN teams can sync and work peacefully ? I decided that the "masterSpace" is redundant and it will never work as I imagined. Still,  I have to find a fast solution for the dcommits so my team won't lose time or code. Some helpful information: we change a branch every 2 weeks aprox. After we finish, we can throw away the used branch and create another one from the master

**Q2: How to make everything automatically?**
In the near future I plan to move my "bridge" on Jenkins. Would it be possible to find a solution to make it work automatically? Something like merging a branch on "jenkinsbranch". Jenkins automatically builds this branch, if its green it dcommits it, if not, waits for another push that will fix the build

In my initial scenario, I planned to have the "masterSpace" as "master" on jenkins. A developer would merge his branch into "masterSpace", jenkins  would make a svn-rebase and build it automatically, if it is green then dcommits all the changes. Else, it waits for a dev to fix the build. But... seems like I was wrong.

TL:DR
What would the normal workflow be when a team works on 2 different branchs for a couple of weeks and wants to dcommit them in SVN (and be in sync with SVN) ?

Comment: Q3 How do I bring the latest updates from SVN to a working branch? git svn rebase (on master) followed by merge or by rebase on working branch ?

Answer (score 0):

I have worked in such environment with git-svn and can say that the sync is difficult to make smooth when the rate of changes/conflicts is high both sides. In your setup I would try to look whether [SubGit](http://www.subgit.com/pricing.html) is as good as they claim to be.

If you stick to git-svn, couple of techniques that might potentially make your life easier:

- Try to avoid merges and use rebases everywhere. Including working branches.  Answering Q3 - do regular rebases of your working branches against your `masterSpace` or `master`.
- I would keep your `masterSpace` separate for convenience of syncing. In my case I called it `master` where the svn branches would use `svn` prefix, e.g. `svn/trunk`. Similarly for other mirrored svn branches. I will use my naming further.
- I wouldn't rebase `master` onto `svn/trunk`. Instead I would first rebase changes from `svn/trunk` onto `master`, if any. At this point I make a technical merge of the `svn/trunk` into `master`. The state of these revisions should be equal (you may check `git diff svn/trunk master`) so in case you get merge conflicts - just do merge with `-s ours`, although I think the recent versions of git were smart enough in this case. Now that `master` is equal to `svn/trunk` and git knows about this via the technical merge, I would rebase the changes from the working branch being merged onto the top of `master`, carry the `master` to those changes (`git push . HEAD:master`), take a detached HEAD of the resulting `master`, and do a dcommit to `svn/trunk`. At this stage we will get `svn/trunk` and `master` again having same contents but different revisions due to svn dcommit. Again, I would do a technical merge of `svn/trunk` to `master` to mark a point of equality.